Gitea - Change the default branch of only one repo
I have a gitea install with several repos, and I need to change the default branch of one of them.  The documentation says that changing DEFAULT_BRANCH value (in the ini file) will change all of the repos.

DEFAULT_BRANCH: main: Default branch name of all repositories.

Is there a way to only change one?

In the settings of the repository.

Each repo has it's own default branch setting located on the settings page.

Click on the settings button that can be found in the upper right corner of practically any page.  It looks like a wrench.
Click on the branches submenu on the left.
The Default Branch setting in at the top.

